# Working with different timezones with Intersystems

Tags: timestamp, timezone, intersystems, intersystems-iris

Quite a complex scenario we are trying to solve but should be able to understand.

We're developing a task executer that runs on a server with a certain timezone.

The tasks run every day at a defined time, but in different timezones.

We're saving in database at what time we want to execute the task, and in what timezone (don't go to the save in UTC pitfall, as with DST it will be at different actual times)

What I want to do if when opening a task from the database, convert 02:00 Europe/Madrid, either to UTC or to local (server) time.

I've found the class HS.Timezone.Server.Service but doesn't solve quite the problem.

Is there any method in intersystems to convert a timestamp from a timezone, to UTC or local?

Comment: "*don't go to the save in UTC pitfall, as with DST it will be at different actual times*" - I think I don't get that part; I mean if you save UTC time + a certain time zone ([IANA tz](https://www.iana.org/time-zones)), you can always convert from UTC to time in that time zone, given the rules of that tz, no?

Comment: If I save my execution time at 04:00 everyday UTC Europe/Madrid... How do I know at what time does the user wants the task to be executed?
I know my user wants 06:00 Europe/Madrid, whatever UTC is, what I need to calculate every day is, at what time do I need to execute my task so it's 06:00 in Madrid

Answer (score 2):

Apparently Intersystems products don't include the tz database, so it's not possible to do it straightforward.
The solution is to call java or python via their embedded mechanisms from intersystems IRIS/Cache.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).